# Null value occur while pass arguments using a named route

Tags: flutter, dart, routes

When I pass the value of userRole from ( Profile screen to Cancel screen ). I am not able to return value using model route. It sends a null value. Please help.

**my profile.dart file**

```
Widget displayProfile(BuildContext context, DataSnapshot dataValues) {
    final values = dataValues.value;
    final userRole = values['role'];
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
        AppPadding.p16,
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [

ListTile(
         title: Text(
         AppString.cancelledOrder,
         style: themeData.textTheme.headline4,
       ),
    trailing: const Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
    onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                 PageRoutes.cancelOrderScreen,
                 arguments: userRole);
              },
         ),
   ],
```

}

**cancelOrder.dart file** where the argument is passed

```
class CancelOrderScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CancelOrderScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CancelOrderScreen> createState() => _CancelOrderScreenState();
}

class _CancelOrderScreenState extends State<CancelOrderScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userRole = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as dynamic;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(userRole),
        ),
),
              
}
```

**my separate route.dart file**

```
class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> getRoute(RouteSettings routeSettings) {
    switch (routeSettings.name) {
      case PageRoutes.profile:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const Profile()); 
      case PageRoutes.cancelOrderScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const CancelOrderScreen());
      default:
        return unDefinedRoute();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `userRole` is not `null` in `displayProfile` Widget ? Also I think you should cast it to `String` instead of ` dynamics`  in `_CancelOrderScreenState` since you use it in a `Text` widget.

Comment: i print userRole in profile.dart file console at it shows the value. But it send null in cancel order screen while navigating.